# List differences in two files using awk

Tags: awk, diff

Say if I have two files -

#### File1:

```
1|abc
2|cde
3|pkr
```

#### File2:

```
1|abc
2|cde
4|lkg
```

How can I list true difference in both files using `awk`? If the second file is a subset of first file, I can do the following -

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} !($1 in a)' file{1,2}
```

But this would give me

```
4|lkg
```

I would like to get output as follows since that is the true difference. The difference should be seen as:

```
3|pkr
4|lkg
```

**Criteria for difference:**

- Field 1 present in file1 but not in file2.
- Field 1 present in file2 but not in file1.
- Field 1 present in both file but has different values.

**Some background:**

File 1 and File 2 are a table export from different databases. It has two fields separated by a pipe delimiter. Field 1 is **always** unique. Field 2 could be same.

My intention is to run `awk` one liner on it to find true differences. If I run the command stated above twice (passing file 1 first for first run and file 2 first for second run) I get my records which are missing in both. However, I want to do this in single pass.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use diff?

Comment: Your example code would print no difference if you have `a|1` in one file and `a|2` in the other.  Is this the intended logic?  Please clarify your question on this point (click the `edit` link and add the updated information).

Comment: If you don't absolutely need awk, use join: `join -v1 -v2 file1 file2`. They need to be sorted; if they're not, use `join -v1 -v2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`. This also adds flexibility, e.g. if you want to ignore the letters even if the numbers don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use awk:

```
$ cat f1
a|1
b|2
c|1
$ cat f2
b|2
c|1
d|0
$ awk '{ h[$0] = ! h[$0] } END { for (k in h) if (h[k]) print k }' f1 f2
a|1
d|0
$
```

Comment: If file1 has 2 same lines (`a|1`), but file2 doesn't have it, your answer will miss it. (mine too ^_^). And if file2 has one line:`a|1` too, your one-liner will report `a|1` is different, which is not correct.

Comment: requirement is not 100% clear, but it is 100% clear that this answer (mine too) doesn't work for all cases. Not generic.

Comment: Thanks @clarkw and @Kent. Your solution ended up giving me more differences since it indexed `$0`. Looks like I have a bigger problem in my database now. Sigh!!

Answer (score 3):

This is what `comm` does:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If say `a|1` is in `file1` once and in `file2` twice then `a|1` will appear once in the output as only one of the occurrences in `file2` was matched in `file1`. If you don't want this behavior and that because `a|1` is seen at least once in each it shouldn't be seen in the output then use the `-u` option with `sort`

```
$ comm -3 <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)
```

Comment: you may want to have `-u` for both `sort`

Comment: @Kent you are possibly right.. Depends on the OP's specification of how duplicates should be handled.

Comment: check the my comment on clarkw's answer. if you replace `b|2` on both file with `a|1`, your output has `a|1` too. with -u, it works for all cases.

Comment: @Kent like I said in my previous comment, you may be right, you may be wrong. The OP didn't specify how to handle duplicates. I have now included both in my answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff file1 file2 | perl -lne 'if(/^[<>]/){s/^..//g;print}'
```

below is the test:

```
> cat file1
a|1
b|2
c|1
> cat file2
b|2
c|1
d|0
> diff file1 file2 | perl -lne 'if(/^[<>]/){s/^..//g;print}'
a|1
d|0
>
```