# Running diff and have it stop on a difference

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I have a script running that is checking multiples directories and comparing them to expanded tarballs of the same directories elsewhere.

I am using `diff -r -q` and what I would like is that when `diff` finds any difference in the recursive run it will stop running instead of going through more directories in the same run.

All help appreciated!

Thank you

@bazzargh I did try it like you suggested or like this.

```
for file in $(find $dir1 -type f); 
do if [[ $(diff -q $file ${file/#$dir1/$dir2}) ]]; 
then echo differs: $file > /tmp/$runid.tmp 2>&1; break; 
else echo same: $file > /dev/null; fi; done
```

But this only works with files that exist in both directories. If one file is missing I won't get information about that. Also the directories I am working with have over 300.000 files so it seems to be a bit of overhead to do a `find` for each file and then `diff`.

I would like something like this to work, with and `elif` statement that checks if `$runid.tmp` contains data and breaks if it does. I added `2>` after the first `if` statement so `stderr` is sent to the `$runid.tmp` file.

```
for file in $(find $dir1 -type f); 

do if [[ $(diff -q $file ${file/#$dir1/$dir2}) ]] 2> /tmp/$runid.tmp; 

then echo differs: $file > /tmp/$runid.tmp 2>&1; break; 

elif [[ -s /tmp/$runid.tmp ]]; 

then echo differs: $file >> /tmp/$runid.tmp 2>&1; break;

else echo same: $file > /dev/null; fi; done
```

Would this work?

Comment: Where comes from the list dirs ? Is it from a shell glob ?

Comment: I have a file that has directory names in it that are checked. Run script with for loop: `for i in cat xaa; do echo $i; ./testtar.sh full $i; done >> xaa-output.log 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the loop over files with 'find' and break when they differ. eg for dirs foo, bar:

```
for file in $(find foo -type f); do if [[ $(diff -q $file ${file/#foo/bar}) ]]; then   echo differs: $file; break; else echo same: $file; fi; done
```

NB this will not detect if 'bar' has directories that do not exist in 'foo'.

Edited to add: I just realised I overlooked the really obvious solution:

```
diff -rq foo bar | head -n1
```

Comment: Your `head` solution doesn't stop `diff`. `diff` completes and then its stdout output is curtailed. How do you mean "obvious solution"? Do you mean somehow incorporate this in the `find` solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'diff', but with 'awk' you can compare two files (or more) and then exit when they have a different line.

Try something like this (sorry, it's a little rough)

```
awk '{ h[$0] = ! h[$0] } END { for (k in h) if (h[k]) exit }' file1 file2
```

Sources are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548801/2327328) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html).

**edit**: to break out of the loop when two files have the same line, you may have to do the loop in awk. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Break-Statement.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Determine directories to compare
d1='./someDir1'
d2='./someDir2'

# Loop over the file lists and diff corresponding files
while IFS= read -r line; do

  # Split the 3-column `comm` output into indiv. variables.
  lineNoTabs=${line//$'\t'}
  numTabs=$(( ${#line} - ${#lineNoTabs} ))

  d1Only='' d2Only='' common=''
  case $numTabs in
    0)
      d1Only=$lineNoTabs
      ;;
    1)
      d2Only=$lineNoTabs
      ;;
    *)
      common=$lineNoTabs
      ;;
  esac

  # If a file exists in both directories, compare them,
  # and exit if they differ, continue otherwise
  if [[ -n $common ]]; then
    diff -q "$d1/$common" "$d2/$common" || {
       echo "EXITING: Diff found: '$common'" 1>&2;
       exit 1; }
  # Deal with files unique to either directory.
  elif [[ -n $d1Only ]]; then # fie
    echo "File '$d1Only' only in '$d1'."
  else # implies: if [[ -n $d2Only ]]; then
    echo "File '$d2Only' only in '$d2."    
  fi

  # Note: The `comm` command below is CASE-SENSITIVE, which means:
  #   - The input directories must be specified case-exact.
  #     To change that, add `I` after the last `|` in _both_ `sed commands`.
  #   - The paths and names of the files diffed must match in case too.
  #     To change that, insert `| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' before _both_
  #     `sort commands.

done < <(comm \
  <(find "$d1" -type f | sed 's|'"$d1/"'||' | sort) \
  <(find "$d2" -type f | sed 's|'"$d2/"'||' | sort))
```

The approach is based on building a list of files (using `find`) containing relative paths (using `sed` to remove the root path) for each input directory, sorting the lists, and comparing them with `comm`, which produces 3-column, tab-separated output to indicated which lines (and therefore files) are unique to the first list, which are unique to the second list, and which lines they have in common.

Thus, the values in the 3rd column can be `diff`ed and action taken if they're not identical.
Also, the 1st and 2nd-column values can be used to take action based on unique files.

The somewhat complicated splitting of the 3 column values output by `comm` into individual variables is necessary, because:

- `read` will treat multiple tabs in sequence as a *single* separator
- `comm` outputs a variable number of tabs; e.g., if there's only a 1st-column value, no tab is output at all.

Comment: Thank you i tried this one but it did not seem to work. Printed out that i had files in each directory that were not the same but they are.

Comment: @user3336916 (revised version of a deleted comment) Could the problem be case-sensitivity? See the comments I added at the end of the loop. To troubleshoot, add the following inside the loop before the if statement: `echo "line: [$(cat -t <<<"$line")]"; echo "$numTabs [$d1Only] [$d2Only] [$common]"`. See whether the output is as expected: First echo shows the whole input line with \t chars. represented as `^I`; the second shows the number of tab chars. in the line and the line parsed into individual columns - see whether you can spot the problem or let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this thanks to @bazzargh.

I use this code in my script and now it works perfectly.

```
for file in $(find ${intfolder} -type f);
do if [[ $(diff -q $file ${file/#${intfolder}/${EXPANDEDROOT}/${runid}/$(basename ${intfolder})}) ]] 2> ${resultfile}.tmp;
then echo differs: $file > ${resultfile}.tmp 2>&1; break;
elif [[ -s ${resultfile}.tmp ]];
then echo differs: $file >> ${resultfile}.tmp 2>&1; break;
else echo same: $file > /dev/null;
fi; done
```

thanks!